# Xuggler errors as soon as you import git

Tags: java, eclipse, git, video-streaming

I downloaded the Git straight into Eclipse for Xuggler ([Here is the git](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler)). But as soon as it loads, there are so many errors I don't know what to do. Most of the errors are "cannot be resolved" type errors.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The import org.junit cannot be resolved AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 22 Java Problem
The import junit cannot be resolved AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 28 Java Problem
TestCase cannot be resolved to a type   AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 30 Java Problem
The import org.slf4j cannot be resolved AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 23 Java Problem
The import org.slf4j cannot be resolved AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 24 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 94 Java Problem
Test cannot be resolved to a type   AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 97 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest      AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 102    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the  type   AtomicIntegerTest   AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 103    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 86 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 89 Java Problem
The   method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest    AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 90 Java Problem
The  method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the   type AtomicIntegerTest   AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 93 Java Problem
Test cannot be resolved to a type   AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com /xuggle/ferry line 114    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 120    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 125    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 126    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 106    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest    AtomicIntegerTest.java    /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 107    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 110    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 111    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 53 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 49 Java Problem
Ignore cannot be resolved to a type AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 57 Java Problem
Test cannot be resolved to a type   AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 56 Java Problem
Before cannot be resolved to a type AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 37 Java Problem
LoggerFactory cannot be resolved    AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 32 Java Problem
Test cannot be resolved to a type   AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 44 Java Problem
The method getName() is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest    AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 40 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 81 Java Problem
Test cannot be resolved to a type   AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 75 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 85 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 82 Java Problem
Test cannot be resolved to a type   AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 64 Java Problem
The  method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 61 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 72 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 69 Java Problem
NameAwareTestClassRunner cannot be resolved BufferTest.java /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 44 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 167    Java Problem
The method debug(String, int, String) in the type Logger is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 166    Java Problem
The method fail(String) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 163    Java Problem
After cannot be resolved to a type  BufferTest.java /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 47 Java Problem
NameAwareTestClassRunner cannot be resolved to a type   BufferTest.java /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 35 Java Problem
The method debug(String, int, String) in the type Logger is not applicable for the arguments (String)   AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line   162  Java Problem
Test cannot be resolved to a type   AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 135    Java Problem
Before cannot be resolved to a type BufferTest.java /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 41 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 131    Java Problem
LoggerFactory cannot be resolved    BufferTest.java /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 38 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AtomicIntegerTest  AtomicIntegerTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/ferry  line 130    Java Problem
The import org.junit cannot be resolved AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 22 Java Problem
The import org.slf4j cannot be resolved AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 23 Java Problem
The import org.slf4j cannot be resolved AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test /src/com/xuggle/xuggler   line 24 Java Problem 
The import junit cannot be resolved AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 31 Java Problem
TestCase cannot be resolved to a type   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 33 Java Problem
Logger cannot be resolved to a type AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 35 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 82 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 80 Java Problem
Logger cannot be resolved to a type AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 89 Java Problem
Logger cannot be resolved to a type AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 84 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 94 Java Problem
Logger cannot be resolved to a type AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 93 Java Problem
Test cannot be resolved to a type   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 99 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 96 Java Problem
Before cannot be resolved to a type AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 37 Java Problem
LoggerFactory cannot be resolved    AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 35 Java Problem
The method getName() is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 40 Java Problem
Logger cannot be resolved to a type AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 40 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 60 Java Problem
Test cannot be resolved to a type   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 43 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 67 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 62 Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 157    Java Problem
Test cannot be resolved to a type   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 161    Java Problem
Logger cannot be resolved to a type AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 154    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 155    Java Problem
The method assertEquals(int, long) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 172    Java Problem
The method assertEquals(long, long) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest  AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 173    Java Problem
The method assertNotNull(IAudioSamples) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest  AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 168    Java Problem
The  method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest  AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 171    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 124    Java Problem
The method assertNotNull(IAudioSamples) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest  AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 129    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 117    Java Problem 
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest    AudioSamplesTest.java  /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 119    Java Problem
Logger cannot be resolved to a type AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 145    Java Problem
Logger cannot be resolved to a type AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 150    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 141    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(String, boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 143    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 216    Java Problem
The method assertEquals(IBuffer.Type, IBuffer.Type) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest  AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 212    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 208    Java Problem
The method assertNotNull(IAudioSamples) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest  AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 204    Java Problem
The method assertEquals(IBuffer.Type, IBuffer.Type) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest  AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 218    Java Problem
The method assertEquals(int, long) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 187    Java Problem
The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 186    Java Problem
The method assertNotNull(IAudioSamples) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest  AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 183    Java Problem
Test cannot be resolved to a type   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 176    Java Problem
Test cannot be resolved to a type   AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 197    Java Problem
The method assertEquals(long, long) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest  AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 192    Java Problem
The method assertEquals(long, long) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest      AudioSamplesTest.java   /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 191    Java Problem
The method assertEquals(long, long) is undefined for the type AudioSamplesTest     AudioSamplesTest.java    /xuggle-xuggler-main/test/src/com/xuggle/xuggler    line 188    Java Problem
```

[image: errors]

For a school project, I would like to build a simple live video stream program (final year in high school) like skype, except not as complicated. Can anyone help me solve these errors? or Is there another platform I can use that would be better/easier?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing dependencies.
Among the missing dependencies is at least junit and slf4j. You will need to install the correct version in your classpath.

Edit: Apparently the project uses ivy, so should you in this case. There is an ivy plugin for eclipse, that might help you.